# Define socket io function outside of "on" statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm writing code with Socket.io in JavaScript and I've been trying to define the function that happens during a certain event outside of the event statement because I want to reuse the function later. So instead of the usual:

```
socket.on('eventName',function(input){
   //code triggered by event
});
```

I want to declare the function beforehand and then use it in the "on" statement:

```
function myFunction(input){
  //some code
}
socket.on('input', myFunction(input));
```

So far I haven't had any success and I keep getting this error in Terminal:

```
nodejs exception: ReferenceError: input is not defined
```

in reference to the input being sent from the client with the 'input' event. Do I always have to define the code that happens when the event is triggered in the "on" statement?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to pass a reference to `myFunction`, like this:

```
socket.on('input', myFunction);
```

What you're doing with `myFunction(input)` is actually *executing* `myFunction` with an undefined variable `input` as its argument (hence the error).